# Drawing right triangle pixel by pixel, line by line?

Tags: java, geometry, aspect-ratio

Here's my code how I draw a right triangle, pixel by pixel, line by line (upside down):

```
double length = 10; double height = 5;
double aspectRatio = length / height;

double limit = 0.0;
int y = 0;

while (y < height) {
    int x = 0;

    while (x < (length - limit)) {
        drawPixel(x, y); // fill pixel on canvas with black at x, y
        x++;
    }

    limit += aspectRatio; // increase "step" how much to cut in length
    // this part here is wrong, the limit increased is too little

    y++;
}
```

My problem is that I don't get a hypotenuse extending from the top right corner to the bottom left corner. This is because I'm doing the calculation wrong and I don't understand how to search for the proper term online to find the calculation I need.

In my code aspectRatio would become 2.0 and when the first full line is drawn pixel by pixel, the next line will be drawn with 2.0 less pixels, the next line again with 2.0 less pixels, etc. This means the 5 lines drawn look something like this:

```
[*][*][*][*][*][*][*][*][*][*]
[*][*][*][*][*][*][*][*][ ][ ]
[*][*][*][*][*][*][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[*][*][*][*][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[*][*][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

However I'm trying to get something like this instead (notice the negative space matches in amount of pixels and is diagonally perpendicular):

```
[*][*][*][*][*][*][*][*][*][*]
[*][*][*][*][*][*][*][*][ ][ ]
[*][*][*][*][*][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[*][*][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Obviously this is mostly a mathematical problem however I don't understand the necessary equations to fix my code. What should I do?

Comment: why not compute the aspect ratio for a triangle one row smaller? i.e. double aspectRatio = length / (height - 1.0) ;

Comment: This code would have to also work with any length / height value, I'm sorry I left that out. E.g. 1300 and 700 respectively. It wouldn't work with your example

Comment: why wouldn't that formula work for any length or height (greater than 1)? Did you test it and it gave the wrong result?

Comment: Yes I test, it doesn't work. E.g. in your example if we had length 1300 and height 700, instead of calculating aspectRatio as length / height, which would give 1.85714285714286, you instead want to calculate as length / (height - 1), or in this case 1300 / 699, which would give 1.85979971387697. The difference between these two values is minuscule. The hypotenuse still ends up being wrong.

Comment: Did you test it by running the program, or just by calculating it? This issue is kind of fence post error: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error Each row is a "fence post" and if there are h rows then there are h-1 steps, so you need to divide by h-1 to get valid values at the end points

Comment: I ran the program it just doesn't make any difference. I believe my problem has more to do with Bresenham line algorithm because I do not incorporate it and don't know how. Please note in my example sometimes the step is (in the example) is 2 or 3 pixels. It should not always be same amount when step is increased.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that pixels are square and have an area, while the x/y coordinates are just points which refer to the top-left corner of the square. This is probably the cause of your confusion/incorrect hypotenuse.

Try something like this (untested):

```
while (y < height) {
    int x = 0;

    // add 0.5 to x/y coordinates to check that the center of the
    // pixel is inside your triangle, not the top left corner.
    while ((float)x + 0.5  < ((float)y + 0.5) * aspectRatio) {
        drawPixel(x, y); // fill pixel on canvas with black at x, y
        x++;
    }

    limit += aspectRatio; // increase "step" how much to cut in length
    // this part here is wrong, the limit increased is too little

    y++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, this code works in a very different way and also results in incorrect hypotenuse. What could be the cause?